# Limited images import to magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, csv, product-import

I'm using magento 1.9 and importing products to system, but noticed strange thing: if product have over 5 images then I have problems to upload csv file, when I leave only 5 or less images (links) than file uploads normally and everything works fine. Any idea what it is?